# How to add custom icon in react select of search filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux-form, react-select

I am working on `react-select` where I need to add custom icon with cross icon when user to select something from dropdown. I really tried hard but did not find any proper solution to resolve my problem . Could someone please help me how to add custom icon in react select .

[Dropdown an attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apDgn.png)

As you see in attachment, you will see cross icon and I want my custom icon with this cross icon .

Comment: check this one : https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-tu9kz?file=/example.js

Comment: @VivekDoshi Thank you for your reply, Actually I want to render icon once not for every option . I want to render icon with cross icon side by side . there I want to close menu

Comment: You can check this example https://codesandbox.io/s/0y320oyq5n?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add an additional icon, you could still create a custom component (say for the ClearIndicator) then just add your icon to the component as a sibling alongside `props.children` and they should both appear on the DOM together

```
    <Select
      components={{
        ClearIndicator: ({ ...props }) => (
          <components.ClearIndicator
            {...props}
          >
            {props.children}
            <NewIcon>Your icon here</NewIcon>
          </components.ClearIndicator>
        ),
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I could find in [this file](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/32ad5c040bdd96cd1ca71010c2558842d684629c/packages/react-select/src/Select.js#L122), there is a `component` prop which takes an object which has [these properties](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/32ad5c040bdd96cd1ca71010c2558842d684629c/packages/react-select/src/components/index.js#L82). You can probably use the `CrossIcon` or `ClearIndicator` property to specify the icon. In the end, it would like this:

```
<Select component={{
    CrossIcon: // Icon here,
    ClearIndicator: // Or here
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, Could you please attach any example

Comment: I think , it will replace react-select crossIcon with new one . I want add new one . Actually, I want two icons side by side .

Comment: I don't think there's any prop to add additional icons but you can use this prop to show icons on that position. Perhaps find an open-source font that looks similar and use that. I haven't used `react-select` before but the library's source code is self-explanatory.